# nginx response status variable

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

I have a question. We use nginx+uwsgi stack and see many errors like:

```
Aug 30 00:00:55 imfmce-va-81-2 uwsgi: Tue Aug 30 00:00:55 2016 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /provisioning/user/f205970b-6a9f-42b5-830f-c2bec9967b32 (ip 10.216.153.254) !!!
```

I understand that error occurs when client close connection before reading response or by uwsgi_read_timeout, but I don't understand why in access log I cannt see any error, nginx just log 200 OK:

```
Aug 30 00:00:55 imfmce-va-81-2 provisioning: active     [ 55544 ]       10.216.153.254  Sync-Wopi-SyncLocksTask hostpilot       73af65e4-5984-4b2c-baf4-c88cf8385898    -       ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     GET     /provisioning/user/f205970b-6a9f-42b5-830f-c2bec9967b32 -       0,0,1,0 200     -       1       OK      -       321     515     844
```

We use next format log line:

```
log_format ss_log_format "active\t[ \$pid ]\t\$remote_addr\t\$http_user_agent\t\$upstream_http_x_user_identity\t\$http_x_client_id\t\$http_x_request_id\t\$ssl_cipher\t\$request_method\t\$uri\t\$args\t\$upstream_http_x_durations\t\$status\t\$upstream_status\t\$http_x_error_code\t\$connection_requests\t\$request_completion\t\$content_length\t\$request_length\t\$body_bytes_sent\t\$bytes_sent";
```

I would like you to understand that,
we don't need to fix this error, we just need have right access logs.